# ANSI escape characters does not appear the way they should on Eclipse console

Tags: eclipse, sbt, ansi-escape

I have a Scala project and I use Scala-Eclipse-Plugin along with sbt. So far so good. But the problem is that sbt writes some ANSI escape sequences to the output (I might be wrong about this?).They appear pretty well when I invoke sbt from shell but inside eclipse, they appear like this:

```
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [34m[0m
```

what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eclipse console does not support ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Any alternatives to the default console ?

Comment: Your own console window implemented in e.g. Swing where ANSI sequences are implemented.  Alternatively create a new Console plugin based on the existing Console panel, where you add ANSI sequence parsing.  THe latter would probably be really nice if contributed back to eclipse.org

Answer (score 3):

See the discussion for "[an eclipse console view that respects ansi color codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286701/an-eclipse-console-view-that-respects-ansi-color-codes)" I followed the suggestion of @thegreendroid and used [ANSIConsole](http://www.mihai-nita.net/eclipse/) successfully.